# How to get appCache Version from the manifest file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-appcache

I have a manifest file starting like this :

```
    CACHE MANIFEST
    # Cache manifest – version & date
    # version 5.2.18
    # 03.05.2013
...
```

I use the version comment to manage the cash when i change the files. Everything works well.

I wanted to know if there is anAPI method/function to have access to the version/date value of the manifest.

Using the File API i am able to read the file and parse it to extract the data but it feels unnatural. 
The browser sure know how to read it but i can't find a specific access viathe API to do so.

Comment: The version string is part of the comments, rather than part of [the spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html). The only reason that the version string causes the app to update is that the manifest file is "different". Unless some kind of version field is added to the spec, I think your only option will be to parse the file yourself.

Comment: Yes and what i found is that every browser handles this its own way, even the format of the version string.